# Can Silent Gravestone prevent someone from casting an Aftermath spell from the graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

A player has [Silent Gravestone](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSilent%20Gravestone%5d) on the battlefield and the opponent has [Commit // Memory](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCommit%5d%2b%5bMemory%5d) in their graveyard, where Memory has Aftermath. Can they cast Memory and would it have its effect on the player with Silent Gravestone?

I don't see Memory targeting anything and couldn't find rules saying aftermath requires you to cast target card from the graveyard.

Answer (score 3):

If you cast [Memory](https://magiccards.info/akh/en/211b.html) from a graveyard, nothing is targeting a card in graveyard. Therefore [Silent Gravestone](https://magiccards.info/rix/en/182.html) won't prevent you casting [Memory](https://magiccards.info/akh/en/211b.html). When [Memory](https://magiccards.info/akh/en/211b.html) resolves, both players shuffle their hand and graveyard into their library, then draw seven cards. [Silent Gravestone](https://magiccards.info/rix/en/182.html) only prevents the casting of a spell (or ability) that targets a card or cards in a graveyard.